# How to use jquery draggable to prevent elements being dragged over each other

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm creating a UI using jquery where multiple elements can be dragged around within a "surface" div.  I don't want to allow any of these to overlap and I could really do with enforcing a margin between them.  Ideally, I'd like this to happen during the drag operation so that the user can see that they can't actually get the elements over (or even too near to) each other and will realise that they need to drop elsewhere.

I've had a look at the containment option and it doesn't look like it will do what I want.  Is there an easy way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery draggable - No overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482388/jquery-draggable-no-overlap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve using http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

Needed to add the draggable options
obstacle: '.elem:not(.ui-draggable-dragging)',
preventCollision: true

where .elem is the class of the draggable elements.

nb. the :not(.ui-draggable-dragging) is required otherwise it prevents collisions with itself and won't move