# How to prevent stacking divs, with jQuery UI drag & drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm stuck on how to prevent dropping when there is already a dropped element in a chosen position.

I have three different sized div elements and I'm dragging them onto a droppable grid. The way I have done my code (see jsFiddle below), I can't think of a way to check if there's already an item there.

Can anyone think of a way, any ideas? **JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sExrV/1/

The code I think would be somewhere in the "drop" event, but I can't think of a way to test for it:

```
$("#grid").droppable({
    accept: (".widget1, .widget2, .widget3"),
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    // test for existing element dropped here??
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery draggable - No overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482388/jquery-draggable-no-overlap)

Comment: the accepted answer to that suggests the "placeholder" function, but that is for the jQuery "sortable", which I'm not using - I'm using "droppable".

Comment: also - the other good answer on that question, with the jquerycollision suggestion, is for detecting collisions on the drag event. The examples on the website fire when hovering over a duplicate - I only want it to run when _dropped_ on a duplicate. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the droppable functionality anytime something is dropped?

```
$("#grid").droppable({
    drop: function() { $( "#grid" ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ); }
});
```